# robolectric: Handler.postDelayed is run immediately

Tags: android, testing, handler, robolectric

I am using Robolectric 3.0 (ToT).

In my activity in `onCreate` I make following call:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 * 60 * 1000)
```

Then in my Robolectric test case I setup the activity and the runnable is immediately started (and as it happens, it calls `finish()`). How can I prevent this from happening?

I used `ShadowLooper.pauseMainLooper();` which prevents firing of the `Runnable`, but that's not a good solution for me. I am sending broadcasts in the test and they don't get received when the main looper is paused. When I unpause it, both the intent is delivered to the broadcast receiver and the `Runnable` is run. How can I get broadcast receiver to run, but not the *delayed* `Runnable`.

Comment: I was able to reproduce same issue with `robolectric 2.4`. I would create ticket on Robolectric issue tracker (I see you already did it) and get their understanding of the problem. Might be as expected. As workaround I would create and proxy class for scheduling delaed events and mock it in the test. It is not nice to write extra functionality for passing your test but it should work

Comment: I filed a ticket: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1509

Comment: This problem appears to be in Android's own scheduler; I'm finding that Handler.postDelayed(foo, 1000) fires off after around 200ms, at least on Android 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much Experience with posting Runnables to the Handler or Using a Looper.If I were you I would use Handler Messages to request a certain action to happen. You could use    `Handler.SendMessageDelayed(message,time)`    in order to delay a task from happening and    `Handler.SendMessage(message)`    for immediate tasks. You need to run your tasks in your Handler's `handleMessage` function. See the Code for an Example.

```
public class incomingHandler extends Handler {
   @Override
   public synchronized void handleMessage(Message msg){
   switch(msg.what){
case 0 : finish(); break;
case 1 : "RUN FUNCTION OR DO SOMETHING ELSE"; break;
default : "HAVE YOUR DEFAULT MESSAGE SERVICE HERE";}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui);
    Handler mHandler = new incomingHandler();
    mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, 1)); 
//This will cause your function to run immediately

    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(null,0),5000L) ;
//This will cause you activity to finish after 5 seconds
}
```

I Hope this Helps.

Comment: This won't help, the send message will be sent immediately too.

Comment: are you still calling the looper ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: are calling this command Looper.getMainLooper().loop(); or something similar to it any where in your code ?

Comment: this code is working for me. I can't figure out why your message isn't delayed. sorry buddy. good luck.  other people maybe able to help you if you post some part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into roboletics I saw that roboletics will run future tasks immediately (why you ask? my guess is that they dont want you to wait for tasks) but will update a variable called **currentTime** (Scheduler.class) to the new fake time.

So you dont wait for tasks ever, pretty much.

And also there seems to be a design flaw in that, they dont actually run the tasks normally because of the no wait thing. 
For example if you will call **handler.sendEmptyMessage()** in **onLooperPrepared()** the task will be issued immediately and will not be queued or wait for the end of the **onLooperPrepared()**  call.

As for now i have tried to mock Looper by myself, and I have some success.